# CSS opacity transition, make it truly linear

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

How can I transition between two divs without seeing the background of the page during the transition.  In this example, I would expect just to see the numbers change:

https://jsfiddle.net/j2td4hd7/15/

The transition easing is set to `linear`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you wrap the content in a div or span and transition that instead of the whole div?

Comment: I may use different backgrounds in the future.  That was just a minimal example.  Here is one with different backgrounds: https://jsfiddle.net/j2td4hd7/15/.  Why does the background of page show during the transition?  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have two elements with black background and opacity of 50% on each of them - they are **not** combined into 100% black :)

Check the following:

```css
div {
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
}
div.half {
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
div.full {
  top: 0;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="half"></div>
<div class="half"></div>
<div class="full"></div>
```

During the animation - the opacity of the two elements is changing from 0 to 100 and from 100 to 0, but the background color is not "combined".

I think the following will provide what you are looking for:

```js
window.swap = function(divId){
 if(divId === 'div1'){
   jQuery('#div1').css('zIndex', 1);
    jQuery('#div2').css('zIndex', 2);
    jQuery('#div2').fadeIn({easing: 'linear', complete: function() {
      jQuery('#div1').fadeOut({easing: 'linear'})
      } }
    );
  }else{
   jQuery('#div2').css('zIndex', 1);
    jQuery('#div1').css('zIndex', 2);
    jQuery('#div1').fadeIn({easing: 'linear', complete: function() {
      jQuery('#div2').fadeOut({easing: 'linear'})
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.block-div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#div2{ display: none; background-color: brown; }
#div1{ background-color: red; }

html, body{
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-div" onclick="swap('div1')" id="div1">1</div>
<div class="block-div" onclick="swap('div2')" id="div2">2</div>
```

> Note regarding comments from the OP:
>   In case you want the same effect with two elements that has different height, you can create two dummy div, one for each div you have. The dummy1 will be in the size of div1, but contain the bg of div2, and same for dummy2. now you can use these dummy divs to do the transition.

Comment: Thank you.  That works great if the DIVs are the same size.  When different sizes, it does not look correct: https://jsfiddle.net/j2td4hd7/18/.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in such case?

Comment: I would like both DIVs to transition at the same time, but doing so causes the page background to be visible.  The delay works, but causes the taller div to stay around until after the shorter div has fully faded in.  This might not be possible to do.

Comment: You can create two dummy div, one for each div you have. The dummy1 will be in the size of div1, but contain the bg of div2, and same for dummy2. now you can use these dummy divs to do the transition :)

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't have anything to do with the easing, it's that you're unnecessarily transitioning both elements.

It's easy to overcomplicate this -- instead think of the two images as a stack: the one on the bottom can stay visible the whole time, only the one on the top needs to fade in and out.

Compare below:

```js
goodswap = function() {
  $('#div2').fadeToggle(); // transitions the top element in and out
}

badswap = function() {
  $('#div1, #div2').fadeToggle(); // transitions both elements in and out
}
```

```css
.block-div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container { position: relative }
#div1 { background-color: red;}
#div2 { background-color: brown; display: none;}
#div3 { background-color: blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="goodswap()">Good fade</button>
<button onclick="badswap()">Bad fade</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block-div" id="div3">(This is the page background)</div>
  <div class="block-div" id="div1">1</div>
  <div class="block-div" id="div2">2</div>
</div>
```

If the images are different sizes, this technique still works so long as the larger one is stacked with the higher z-index.  To keep the rest of the page from jumping around, set the container's size to that of the larger image.

```js
goodswap = function() {
  $('#div2').fadeToggle(); // transitions the top element in and out
}

badswap = function() {
  $('#div1, #div2').fadeToggle(); // transitions both elements in and out
}
```

```css
.block-div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container { position: relative }
#div1 { background-color: red;}
#div2 { background-color: brown; width: 500px; display: none;}
#div3 { background-color: blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="goodswap()">Good fade</button>
<button onclick="badswap()">Bad fade</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="block-div" id="div3">(This is the page background)</div>
  <div class="block-div" id="div1">1</div>
  <div class="block-div" id="div2">2</div>
</div>
```